# old dates in datetime field

Tags: datetime

I need to be able to enter old dates. I am not allowed to enter anything prior 1880.
Using drupal 9, datetime field.

Daterange does not allow to enter anything before 1900.

Any workaround or solution?

Comment: I can only go back to 1921 on windows 10, so the fact that Drupal can go back until 1880 seems impressive. The ugly workaround would be to use a text field instead of the datetime

Comment: I found a module. yearonly. which so far is a workaround for me. By default, it is from 1900, but you can edit a yml file containing the range definition. An ideal solution should be a standard datetime field though.